# Create Python list of list with random numbers and lengths

Tags: python, list, random

How to create create a list of lists with random numbers in Python? The length of the list and the sub-lists will be random too.I tried this.

```
import random
p= []
for a in range(random.randint(5,7)):
   p.append(random.randint(1,20))
k=[]
for b in range(random.randint(4,8)):
   k.append(p)
print k
```

why it did not work?

Comment: this time you may be lucky, but next time keep in mind that SO isn't a code-writing service. You need to show your attempts. Also, please read how to ask and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It was my first time. I tried to add the code but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random
my_randoms = random.sample(xrange(101), 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

using a list comprehension and [random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

```
import random as ra

r1 = 10
r2 = 20
r3 = 30
lst = [[ra.randrange(r1) for _ in range(ra.randrange(r2))] for __ in range(ra.randrange(r3))]
print(lst)
```

e.g. produces

```
[[2, 2, 6, 0, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6],
 [2, 4],
 [8, 2, 2, 0, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 0, 9, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 8, 6],
 [8, 4, 2, 3, 7, 2, 1, 7, 0, 0, 8],
 [7],
 [7, 2],
 [0, 6, 9, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 4, 6, 1, 5, 3, 6],
 [4, 5, 7, 1, 8, 6],
 [7, 5, 1, 2, 5],
 [8, 6],
 [9, 9, 8, 5, 3, 8, 5],
 [3, 2, 3, 4, 8, 8, 9, 3],
 [1, 1],
 [0, 8, 6, 3, 6, 6, 9, 1, 4, 7, 4, 0, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2]]
```

Note: on Python 2 use `xrange` instead of `range`

Comment: [x for x in xrange(int(10*random()), int(1000 * random()), int(100 * random()))]

Comment: @AlokThakur I see now you have put your idea to good use posting your solution as an answer. Where it belonged from the start. There's plenty of room for different options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.sample` provided your range is larger than the number of random variables you select from it. This approach ensures each random value in the nest list is unique:

```
from random import randint
import random

number_of_lists = randint(0,1000)

random_data = []
for number in xrange(0,number_of_lists):    
    list_length=randint(0,1000)
    random_data.append(random.sample(range(1, 100000), list_length))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import random   
 [x for x in xrange(int(10*random()), int(1000 * random()), int(100 * random()))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
[random.sample(xrange(10), random.randint(0,9)) for _ in range (random.randint(0,9))]
```